# Event of conflict Between UIScrollView and UIPageControl

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

```
//AppDelegate.m
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions{
...
appStartController = [[NavViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = appStartController;
...  }

//NavViewController.h
@property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *pageScroll;
@property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

//NavViewController.m
...
[pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(getChangePage:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void)getChangePage:(UIPageControl *)pageControl
{
int page = pageControl.currentPage;
CGRect frame = pageScroll.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[pageScroll scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
if(page!=pageControl.currentPage){
pageControl.currentPage = page;   }
}
```

it looks well and can run well.
But my problem is when I click pageControl,and its currentNumber changed then the pageScroll turnTo currentNumber , the currentNumber will turn to the last one quickly and then turn back. I know the reason,But I don't know how to solve this problem.

for  example:
currentNumber = 1;
When I click right part, currentNumber=2 -> scroll start move -> 1 ->move more than a half -> 2 
of course, the time is very short .
how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

here's how I solved it:

First, when pager clicked, I set bool indicator to it:

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
    animationPerforming = YES; //animation indicator
    //perform scrolling
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

}
```

Then on scrollViewDidScroll I simply don't change anything if animationPerforming equal YES.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {e
    if (animationPerforming) {
        return;
    }
    //else change page number
}
```

And after animation is completed, I set animationPerforming to NO. This is method from

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    animationPerforming = NO;
}
```

Hope it helped.